# Inconsistency with class new DateTime PHP

Tags: php, date

I need get the range by hours starting of the acctually hour, example: If in this moment are at 05:25, i need get 05:00 and 06:00.

I have this code:

```
$currentHour = (new DateTime())->format('H:00');
$nextHour    = (new DateTime('+59 minutes'))->format('H:00');
$timeRangeFinal   = [$currentHour, $nextHour];
```

If the present hour not is 01:00, 02:00, 03:00... the code work fine, but if the present hour is for example 02:00, the array is same, $timeRangeFinal[0] = "02:00" and $timeRangeFinal[1] = "02:00".

How can i get the range by a hour with *:00?

Comment: Do `+60 minutes`…?! Or `->format('H') + 1`…?

Comment: Why are you adding 59 minutes? 02:00 + 59 minutes is 02:59. Since you're formatting it as :00, it will still be 02:00.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line of code

```
$nextHour    = (new DateTime('+59 minutes'))->format('H:00');
```

to this

```
$nextHour    = ((new DateTime())->modify('+1 hour'))->format('H:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

i have written a little bit for you. this is a way to do it but it it is in the way you are adding 1 hour on top of it.
i have written a small selution (this also helps me learing so i am happy to do it).

```
$currenttime = new \DateTime();
$currenttimehour = $currenttime->format('H:00');
$nextHour = $currenttime->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'))->format('H:00');

echo $currenttimehour;
echo ' ';
echo $nextHour;
```

this is going from the current time. it first format's it to the hour you are in. next it wil add the 1 hour extra you need and format it to the correct format.
i hope i could be of some help to you.